# Номера при повторном запуске

Tags: python

[image: Номер при повторном запуске.]

При повторном запуске файла он открывается с номером (1,2,3,4,5), как это убрать? PyCharm

Comment: не могли бы вы показать ваш код? Я бы посоветовал вам изменить вариант открытия файла, если вам нужно в него что-то записать, то сделайте тип открытия `'r'`, если файл уже существует и вы хотите что-то добавить, то сделайте тип `'a'`, а в вашем случае у вас скорее всего тип открытия файла `'w'` и python не находит нужный вам файл => создаёт новый файл.

Comment: Имеется в виду что вы в редакторе файл повторно открываете или что имеется в виду под запуском?

Comment: Когда я нажимаю в первый раз run, то он запускает name.py, когда нажимаю повторно, не закрывая первый, то у меня открывается name (1).py, потом name(2).py и т.д. Есть такая функция, которая сама будет закрывать (или скрывать) первый файл, чтобы не засорялась строка с запущенными файлами?